# How to navigate in dialog's file and directory selectors?

Tags: files, dialog

I wrote some shell scripts using `dialog` prompting the user for directories and files. However, I don't know how to change the directory. When I press Space in a `dselect`, the directory gets added to the path displayed, but pressing Enter is like selecting `OK`.

So, how to navigate through the directories?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are using `dialog` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797364/rudimentary-file-explorer-using-dialog-boxes-with-fselect-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually [`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) provides the ability to navigate around the file system, going up to parent directories or down to subdirectories.  Here is a brief description of how it works:

- starting with a `--dselect` widget, you see a screen with two panes and two buttons.
- One button is *OK*, the other is *Cancel*.
- The top (usually larger) pane has a title *Directories*.
- The other pane is unlabeled.  It is your work-area for the directory-path which the widget may print.
- You can always use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key (and depending on the terminal, <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>) for moving the cursor to the next (or previous) item of those four, in a loop.
- Where the cursor lies, that is the active location.  An <kbd>Enter</kbd> always completes the dialog, but in the two panes, the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> has different meanings.
- If you press the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> while in the *Directories* pane, the widget append the currently-selected item into the work-area (if it is not already part of the path).
- You can use the up/down arrow-keys for moving the cursor up/down, to select a different item.
- If you type any printable character (including the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> which copies into the work area), the cursor moves to the work-area, as well as moving the selection in the *Directories* pane to the closest partial match of the name.
- While in the work-area, if you delete characters from the path, e.g., a trailing `"/"`, the *Directories* pane adjusts as necessary to show directories which might be selected.  For example, if the work-area holds `/usr/bin`, and you delete the `/bin` from the end, the *Directories* pane will show the `/usr` directory.

The `--fselect` dialog works the same way (it *is* the same code), but shows two panes at the top, for *Directories* and *Files*.

[image]

Comment: This works, but who thought of this...? This is the most unintuitive file/directory selector I have seen so far. Guess I have to find another ncurses-based fileselector or roll my own...

Comment: Fair enough, i delete my wrong answer. it's the first time i hear about this.